# Grouped, Rolling, Product of Lagged Value Column and Another Column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get a grouped, rolling product of one lagged column and one not lagged column **without using a loop**. My numerous attempts at using different lambda and apply combinations have failed. I am trying to do the following:

By **Group column** fill in the **Price column** by looking back at the previous year's price and multiplying by the current year's (1+factor) on a rolling basis (see below top for starting table and below bottom for  what I want to get).

[image: Starting Table][image: Ending Table]

```
# DataFrame for starting values
d = {'Group': [1,1,1,1], 'Year': [2023, 2024, 2025, 2026],
     'Price': [17.324, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN], 'Factor': [0.019, 0.021, 0.022, 0.022]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

My problem seems to mostly stem from the fact that I have to apply a custom function and not something like .mean() as seen in the chain below and that I want use two columns in calculation. Replacing .mean() with a custom function appears invalid.

```
# Type of approach I was trying to employ - replacing the .mean() with custom function
df.groupby(['Group'])['Price'].apply(lambda x: x.rolling(1).mean().shift())
```

I also tried something like this - which also didn't work. I know my attempts have become screwy - please help!

```
def custom_function(col, factor):
    adj = col.shift() * (1+factor)
    return adj

df.groupby(['Group']).apply(lambda x: custom_function(x['Price'], x['(Factor']))
```

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible to do this without a `for` loop. This type of iterative calculation where the inputs depend on results of previous steps, I think would limit vectorization.

Answer (score 0):

Look like you are working with inflation data. `cumprod` is function you are looking for:

```py
def calc(group):
    first_price = group['Price'].iloc[0]
    
    # Do not mutate the object you are iterating over. Make your own copy
    factor = group['Factor'].copy() 
    factor.iloc[0] = 0

    return group.assign(
        CumFactor=factor.add(1).cumprod(),
        NewPrice=first_price * factor.add(1).cumprod()
    )

df.groupby('Group').apply(calc).reset_index(drop=True)
```

The `CumFactor` column was added for illustration only. You can rename `NewPrice` to `Price`.

Comment: `.add(1).cumprod()` is a nice approach, but I think the end result can be accomplished with a one liner: `df['Price'] = df['Price'].min() * df['Factor'].add(1).where(df['Price'].isna(), 1).cumprod()`